# Laravel UserPolicy always rejects authorization

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I have made a `UserPolicy` in Laravel, and am trying to use the `$this->authorize(User::class)` in the controller, however, it always returns 403 error when I visit the `UserController@index`, this problem isn't present if I remove the `$this->authorize(User::class)` from `UserController`

**app/Providers/AuthServiceProvider.php**

```
namespace App\Providers;

use App\Transaction;
use App\Policies\UserPolicy;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $policies = [
        User::class => UserPolicy::class
    ];

    /**
     * Register any authentication / authorization services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        //
    }
}
```

**app/Policies/UserPolicy.php**

```
namespace App\Policies;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;

class UserPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can index users.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $model
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function index(User $user)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**app/Controllers/UserController.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $this->authorize(User::class);
        $users = User::all();
        return view('users.index', compact('users'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried passing the user instance instead of class name `$this->authorize(auth()->user())` ?

Comment: @linktoahref Just tried doing so, but nothing changed

Comment: Is the user logged in while accessing the index route of User Controller ?

Comment: @linktoahref Yes, I am able to access the auth routes

Comment: try $this->authorize('index', User::class);

Comment: @MikeFoxtech still unauthorized, however, I have made another policy using another model ('TransactionPolicy' and 'Transaction'), and it seems to work just fine

Comment: in app/Providers/AuthServiceProvider.php add **use App\User;**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`use App\User;` was missing from `app/Providers/AuthServiceProvider.php`, thanks [Mike Foxtech](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9608853/mike-foxtech) for the [answer in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49884133/laravel-userpolicy-always-rejects-authorization?noredirect=1#comment86789153_49884133)

> in app/Providers/AuthServiceProvider.php add use App\User;